# LPWSTR, wchar_t* and unsigned short pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, unsigned, short, wchar

I'm trying to understand if these types are all the same. I have this function from *windows.h*:  `GetCommandLine()`, in `UNICODE` mode, and it returns a `LPWSTR`. Now, if I dig deeper I can see how `LPWSTR` is `wchar_t*` and if I go even further, I find out that `wchar_t` is `unsigned short` (16 bytes) or `unsigned long` (32 bytes). Yet, if I do this:

```
unsigned short* SysComm = GetCommandLine();
```

I get this error:

> cannot convert from 'LPWSTR {aka wchar_t*} to 'short unsigned int*' in initialization

So, does the compiler follow the same logic to find out that `LPWSTR` is `unsigned short*` in the end or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wchar_t` is a distinct type that is defined to have the same properties as one of the other integer types.

> Type `wchar_t` is a distinct type [...]. Type `wchar_t` shall have the same size, signedness, and alignment requirements (3.11) as one of the other integral types, called its *underlying type*.

So you can't implicitly convert from a `wchar_t*` to a `short*` just as much as from an `int*` to a `short*`.

Comment: But can I cast from int* to short*, for example?

Comment: @ali Not implicitly. You could do it with a `reinterpret_cast`, but that would be a bad idea. You can cast from an `int` to a `short`, but not between pointers to each of them.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I say `typedef int myint` then `myint` and `int` are not the same for the compiler, even if they have the same size, right?

Comment: @ali A `typedef` is different. They are not strongly typed. In that case, `myint` and `int` will be considered the same. `wchar_t` is not just a `typedef`ed type.